# PC clone to MAC PRO

Tags: windows-xp, mac-pro

i want to clone my PC hard drive (XP) to a new MAC PRO using bootcamp. I install bootcamp partition on MAC and hook up firewire between them. I am using XXCLONE on PC but when it finds the MAC bootcamp partition..in mycomputer...XXCLONE does not recognize or find the MAC partition...also, BOOTcamp seems to only allow FAT32 format and not NTSC..
HELP!!

can i play large 5GB vioeo files on the bootcamp partition?? doesn't seem possible if FAT32

Answer (score 1):

Even if you'll manage to copy the files over, your XP won't boot on your Mac Pro.
XP and to a lesser degree Windows 7 really do not like to be moved to a totally different hardware. As part of Windows install there's installation of system-critical drivers, which are specific only to a particular hardware. These drivers from your PC won't work on your Mac Pro. You'll end up with Blue Screen of death. Furthermore, thigns are complicated by the fact that this is a Mac and the away Apple implemented their "bootcamp" feature.

Your best bet is to do a clean XP(or Win7) install on your Mac Pro and then find some software to migrate the data/some applications over.

Comment: thanks, curious that previous threads indicate cloning success...apprecate the insight/warning.

Comment: Can you point to such threads? Are you sure they were performed on dissimilar hardware like yours or one Mac to another?