# How to install Windows 7 on a MacBook Air through Device Sharing from an ISO file?

Tags: windows-7, installation, iso-image, macbook-air

I am trying to install Windows 7 on a MacBook Air using Boot Camp. I've read that it can be done through Device Sharing with a PC so the Windows 7 DVD will be read in the optical drive of the PC, since the MBA doesn't have one.

I have a laptop that has no optical drive but I have PowerISO so I can mount the Windows 7 ISO on it.

How would I go about installing Windows 7 with this setup?

Comment: I don't know exactly how Device Sharing works, but have you tried mounting the ISO on the Windows laptop and seeing if the MBA sees the virtual optical drive?

Answer (score 1):

If you can mount the Windows 7 iso on a virtual drive then just download the iso and run it. There are copies of it on the internet but you will still need the serial key on the box. You can also install Windows 7 by using the Windows 7 USB installer thing a majig linked below. This is done by downloading the Windows 7 iso and then mounting it using the installer. Good luck.

USB installer: http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool

ISO:http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-links/

Comment: Looks like this guy is trying to do what you recommended http://superuser.com/questions/553195/pc-clone-to-mac-pro

Answer (score 1):

Boot Camp takes an ISO file and automatically creates a bootable USB thumb drive from it. It just needs 4 GB of space, if I remember correctly.